# Merge [firefox-addon-webextensions] into [firefox-addon]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) already includes extensions and themes, etc. Nowadays most people only write WebExtensions for Firefox and not legacy extensions. So I think it's worthwhile to merge the tag [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) into [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon). [firefox-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extension) is already a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with this proposal. While it is true that *now* WebExtensions are the primary type of add-on which is functional in the Release version of Firefox, they are not the only type of add-on in existence. Historically, there have been the following types of Firefox add-ons ([brief old intro to Firefox add-on types archived from Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324)):

- Overlay ([firefox-addon-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-overlay)) (also called XUL extensions/add-ons)
- Bootstrap ([firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap)) (originally called "Restartless")
- Add-on SDK ([firefox-addon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk))
- WebExtensions ([firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions))
- [WebExtensions Experiments](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)<sup>1</sup>
- Hybrid Bootstrap/WebExtensions (used to transfer data from legacy to WebExtensions)
- Studies (and some specialty types reserved to Mozilla)
- Themes (yes, these are separate from the other two theme types)
- Lightweight Themes
- Browser Themes
- Mobile add-ons
- Search engine plugins
- User dictionaries
- Language packs
- Plugins

There's also the [firefox-addon-restartless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-restartless) tag. Originally, this meant just [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap), as "restartless" was originally used as the name/synonym for bootstrap add-ons. However, when the Add-on SDK was created, "restartless" functionally described Add-on SDK based add-ons too<sup>2</sup>. At that point, Mozilla moved to using "bootstrapped" instead of "restartless". As such, the use of the [firefox-addon-restartless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-restartless) tag became blurred. Ideally, the questions in the [firefox-addon-restartless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-restartless) would be disambiguated into [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap) and [firefox-addon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk), but it's not clear to me that it's worth the effort at this point.

Even if we are only talking about add-on types which are possible to use in current versions of Firefox, then there are still:

- WebExtensions ([firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions))
- Browser Themes
- WebExtensions Experiments
- Studies (and some specialty types reserved to Mozilla)
- Some legacy types with `extensions.legacy.enabled` in Nightly and Developer Edition

So, [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) should not be merged into [firefox-addons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addons), or even be made a synonym.

#### We should rename [firefox-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-webextensions) to [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) [DONE]

To keep with the already existing tag naming scheme, the [firefox-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-webextensions) tag should have been called [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions). However, at the time the tag was created, the limit on number of characters in a tag prevented doing so. The [maximum number of characters in a tag has been raised to 35 since then](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/271271). At this point, it would be possible to rename the tag to match the naming used for tags for the other types of Firefox add-ons.

Note: I agree that there we could do a significant amount of clean-up/disambiguation for these tags, but it's not really clear to me that doing so at this point is worth the time and effort.

---

[Note: I am the top contributor in [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions). I'm also in at least the top 7 in all of the firefox-addon tags.]

1. <sub>WebExtensions Experiments are an amalgam of overlay/bootstrap add-ons and WebExtensions. They are primarily intended to be run on Nightly and Developer Edition to prototype new APIs for WebExtensions, but Mozilla demonstrated that they can function on the Release version of Firefox when they released [one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disabled-add-on-fix-61-65/) as a stopgap solution to [Add-ons disabled or failing to install in Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2019/05/04/update-regarding-add-ons-in-firefox/) in May of 2019.</sub>
2. <sub>Functionally Add-on SDK add-ons are Bootstrap add-ons, but with a wrapper that gives them a specialized environment and several APIs.</sub>