# [firefox-addon]: consolidate into [firefox-addon-webextensions] and [firefox-addon-overlay]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I know something similar [has been proposed before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389447/1874170), however, I think that, as it stands, it'd be appropriate to do one of the following:

- Rename [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) into a tag for questions that are **explicitly and immutably about Add-Ons built on the XUL/XPCOM framework** (ex: [240362](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240362/1874170), [724605](https://stackoverflow.com/q/724605/1874170), [877884](https://stackoverflow.com/q/877884/1874170)), because otherwise it's redundant with [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions). I don't believe there is enough relevant overlap between XUL Add-On development and WebExtension development to be worth having some ambiguity there.

  - Either it could just be merged into [xul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul), or perhaps renamed into a new tag, say, [xul-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul-addon) — this would not only be to properly segregate historical questions which, if tagged [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) **might be misleading** to people looking for merely "Firefox addon" questions in [current year]; but **also to aid** those seeking questions wrt XUL/XPCOM for browsers such as [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/).
- Just burninate [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) and mark it as an alias of [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) (for future questions), but also put a note at the end of its description saying that "legacy" questions with the tag which are unambiguously about XUL/XPCOM Add-Ons should (when noticed) be re-tagged to something else.

  - Perhaps go ahead and auto-retag as [xul-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xul-addon) all [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) questions posted before a certain date, or that are *not* also tagged with [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) — just to get the first-order bulk of them tidied?

(I'm aware that these "two" suggestions are somewhat overlapping and not entirely mutually exclusive in any case; I'm trying to stimulate some discussion on how to clean things up — the [>7k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon?sort=Oldest&filters=None) are not going to become any *less* of a mess by themselves as time goes on…)

In short, [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) is currently in a weird ambiguous state that I believe could be much better than it is. It's **redundant** when applied to [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) questions, but **useless** for those actually looking for XUL/XPCOM Add-On development information due to its applicability to FF-WE questions. I don't see *any* benefit or purpose to keeping the tag as-is (other than saving labor / opportunity-cost), so I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: > *I don't believe there is enough relevant overlap between XUL Add-On development and WebExtension development to be worth having some ambiguity there.* < To expand on this, I think that there's already some precedent for "segregating" tags for different extension platforms: [tag:firefox-addon-webextensions] is separate from [tag:google-chrome-extension], despite being *actually compatible with each other* when eschewing vendor-specific APIs — how much more, then, would it be appropriate to segregate out *incompatible* platforms, powered by different languages? `2015:Firefox` ≠ `2020:Firefox`

Comment: Also, am I the only one bothered by this inconsistency: `firefox-addon` (singular), `google-chrome-extension` (singular), `firefox-addon-webextensions` (plural)? ‎

Comment: AFAIK, the plural/singular thing was because of how the features where marketed. [WebExtensions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebExtensions) for the plural.

Comment: Hmm, I just found [tag:firefox-addon-overlay] — it _looks like_ this is supposed to be the tag for [XUL/Overlay Add-Ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) — what I penciled in as `xul-addon` in the Question — and, tangentially, it's not clear that the short-lived pre-WebExtension [Bootstrapped/Restartless platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) ever got enough traction to warrant its own tag.

Comment: Why? Firefox extensions are still called Add-ons.

Comment: NOTE: I renamed [tag:firefox-webextensions] to [tag:firefox-addon-webextensions] and have updated all references to the tag on this page.

Comment: I originally didn't close this question as a duplicate of [Merge \[firefox-addon-webextensions\] into \[firefox-addon\]](/q/389447/merge-firefox-webextensions-into-firefox-addon), because you acknowledged the existence of that declined proposal and were asking for another look to be taken at the situation. I also felt that, perhaps, I was too close to the situation. However, your answer here appears to indicate that you didn't even read the answer I wrote to that prior proposal. I'm not categorically against some reorganization of the tags for Firefox add-ons, but more nuance is needed.

Comment: @TylerH probably historical reasons.

Answer (score -3):

Upon further looking-into-it, I have found an existing tag matching the "legacy" (XUL overlay) add-ons, so my proposal would be:

Burninate [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon). Send all its questions to either [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions), [firefox-addon-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-overlay), or [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap), depending on which platform they're about.

IMO, breaking this redundant tag up in favor of the *existing* tags, which already cover *all* of its interpretations, would be an extremely clean and obviously correct solution for the long run, that respects askers and answerers across present and past versions of Firefox, as well as those developing for XUL-based forks; but I'd love to hear any other perspectives.

(Additionally, it looks like [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap) should subsume [firefox-addon-restartless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-restartless) entirely; restartlesness was a feature added by the Bootstrapped API, and is its primary draw. The tag [firefox-addon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk) is out-of-scope of this question except as a way to infer [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap) for non-specifically-categorized questions; it, itself, should not be modified.)

---

This looks intimidating at first, given that there are over 7 thousand questions with the tag — of which, [Makyen points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405769/firefox-addon-consolidate-into-firefox-addon-webextensions-and-firefox-add#comment838986_407043), nearly 5 thousand of which are *not* already categorized more specifically.

Given that [Bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) were released with Firefox 4, on March 22nd 2011, and both it and [XUL Overlay extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) were not removed until the release of Firefox 57 on November 14th 2017, it can broadly be assumed that the ~3.5k affected questions published between those dates cannot be automatically categorized. This leads to a non-trivial organizational effort to sort and archive the historical questions, and may not be doable immediately.

---

Therefore, I propose to, for now:

- formally deprecate [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) in favor of the more specific tags; prevent future questions from being tagged with it, directing askers primarily to [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) given that it's the only technology supported by mainline Firefox
- for questions already tagged with [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions), [firefox-addon-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-overlay), or [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap), automatedly remove the tag [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon)
- for questions tagged with *none of* [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions), [firefox-addon-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-overlay), or [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap):

  - those published in [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) before 2011-03-22, automatedly retag to [firefox-addon-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-overlay)
  - those published in [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) after 2017-11-14, automatedly retag to [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions)
  - those published in [firefox-addon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon) that also have tag [firefox-addon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-sdk), automatedly retag to [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap)
- burninate [firefox-addon-restartless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-restartless) in favor of [firefox-addon-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-bootstrap) (or vice-versa as per site admin discretion)
- optionally, look into making arrangements for the "archival categorization" of the ~3.5k remaining questions which *only* have the ambiguous tag

> Commonly, you should use this tag IN ADDITION TO the tag for the specific type of add-on which you are asking about.
> – https://stackoverflow.com/tags/firefox-addon/info

As it stands, I cannot see why to keep this self-professedly redundant tag in use for *new* questions, and would in any case propose that at least it be deprecated with direction to [firefox-addon-webextensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firefox-addon-webextensions) immediately.

Comment: I disagree with this proposal (note: I'm the top answerer for both the [tag:firefox-addon-webextensions] and [tag:firefox-addon-overlay] tag, and am the fourth highest answerer for [tag:firefox-addon]). While I'm not categorically against some reorganization, this proposal does not account for the multiple types of add-ons which Firefox has had in the past, a subset of which it still has the capability to use. I agree that most people who have recently gotten into the Firefox add-on ecosystem will primarily be focused on WebExtensions, but that's not all that's there.

Comment: Your estimate for the number of questions with one of the other tags is over-optimistic. There are [4,932 questions not containing the text webextensions & tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+-webextensions+%5Bfirefox-addon%5D+-%5Bfirefox-addon-webextensions%5D+-%5Bfirefox-addon-overlay%5D+-%5Bfirefox-addon-bootstrap%5D+-%5Bfirefox-addon-sdk%5D+-%5Bfirefox-addon-restartless%5D&searchOn=1) with [tag:firefox-addon] not [tag:firefox-addon-webextensions] not [tag:firefox-addon-overlay] not [tag:firefox-addon-bootstrap] not [tag:firefox-addon-sdk] not [tag:firefox-addon-restartless].

Comment: You describe this proposal as “not account[ing] for the multiple types of add-ons”, however, I'm failing to see which ones I've missed. The poposal takes into account not only the two major ones (WebExtension and Overlay), but also the abandoned, obscure type ([Bootstrapped _aka_ Restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) — it appears that there's a duplicate tag there). The Add-On SDK is software toolchain Mozilla has maintained with a varying degree of rigor and scope throughout the years that probably shouldn't be touched by this proposal.

Comment: @Makyen I have updated the proposal in light of your notes about the volume of questions (it's, indeed, worse than I had initially estimated,) and also with greater specificity on exactly why I'm confident that the tag _is_ redundant as-is.

Comment: You appear to have ignored the fact that there are 11 additional add-on types which do not have their own more specific tag, which do fall under the purview of [tag:firefox-addon]. That tag is not fully redundant. The significant majority of questions do fall into the more specific tags, but not all. There are also questions which are more about the general ecosystem, which don't fall under any of the more specific tags.

Comment: Date based automatic retags: the situation is messier than you appear to be allowing for, with multiple add-on types coexisting during multiple times, even if most the common type during a time-period is as you've mentioned. Dates can be used to eliminate possibilities and to indicate that some types of add-on are more likely than others, but there are no periods which categorically eliminate the other possibilities. [I'd need to double-check for the early years, as I'm not sure when some of the less common types were introduced. Overlay may have been the only option for very early years].

Comment: You still haven't answered why you want to burninate [firefox-addons], since that is still what user extension in Firefox are called.

Comment: @TylerH Because, as far as I can tell, it's redundant. You claimed that I'm missing some types, and listed some tags as evidence, but did not clarify when I responded showing that my proposal already took all of those into account.